# When would Microsoft Bot Framework finish their preview for Skype For Business channel and launch for production?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

We are looking to develop a BOT for enterprise space and I was wondering if there is any roadmap available for SkypeForBusiness channel to be in production. We are using Microsoft Bot Framework for our Bot development and want to know when the channel, which is currently in preview, can be used in production. I have tried looking for it online but I am unable to find any update.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, Skype for business is not in preview.

Comment: I have updated the question. I wanted to ask about Microsoft Bot Framework and the use of SkypeForBusiness Channel in that.

Comment: Skype for business is not in preview, and Bot Framework v3 is not in preview as well. However, v4 is in preview.  So if you are using v3 both products you are using are not in preview and are good to go for production use,  if you are using v4 there is no concrete release date to share at this time.

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview

It says that Skype for business channel for bot framework is in the preview. This is what I am referring to.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link, this is news to me.  Let me reach out to the docs team and see what the deal is with this documentation.  Thank you for bringing this to our attention

Answer (score 0):

@Waqas Zia: Not sure if I'm answering exactly what you want. Hopefully you are aware of the annonuncement at last Ignite that [Microsoft is integrating Skype for Business capabilities into Teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/09/25/a-new-vision-for-intelligent-communications-in-office-365/) and encouraging customers to upgrade to Teams as their primary communication / collaboration experience in CY18 as it meets their needs. [Roadmap coming for Skype for Business to Teams convergence](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/Roadmap-for-Skype-for-Business-capabilities-coming-to-Microsoft/ba-p/119636) is now available. Hope this helps to plan accordingly. We don't have ETA yet about launch for production.